# Importing jar and a type is indirectly referenced from required .class file

Tags: junit, jar, import, xml-parsing, test-class

I was searching for a jar file from internet and I got a java project which contains that jar file. Now when I copied that jar file to my project and included them in my libraries, I have an error in the line of package name.

Copying the jar from another project, Is it a wrong way?

Or if it is right, Is there anyway I could rectify this error?

Error: The type org.junit.internals.runners.TestClassRunner cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class file

I am in need of this XMLParameterizedRunner class. If any one could get me the link to the jar with this class, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Do check [issues list](https://code.google.com/p/junitext/issues/detail?id=8) of Junitext , many other have reported similar issue.

Actually *XMLParameterizedRunner* extends *TestClassRunner* and *TestClassRunner* is missing from JUnit 4.5 .

It seems you might have JUnit version > 4.4. So do check with JUnit 4.4 and this issue will be gone. I have checked example test with 4.4 and no such error seen.

Comment: Now the type error has gone, but still I have an error when I use the annotation XMLParameters to include the testData.xml.

Error:The annotation @XMLParameters is disallowed for this location.